# Wordpress blog links are redirecting to home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress, I have downloaded the wp folders and files from server to localsystem with db.

Now the problem is if I create any posts and added those post to blog category and now I am trying to display them. But the permalinks are going to home page.
For example:www.example.com/connectivity is the actual post permalink. Even though it goes there but the page will be home page contents.
For example: www.example.com.

Please help me to resolve this.
What I have tried:
1)changed setting of permalinks in wp-admin. It did not work well.
2)I have manually changed by updating database queries for tables wp_options,wp_posts and .htaccess file. But there was no changes.

What could be the possible reason here and please let me know how can I resolve this.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Have you changed all links in your database?

Comment: @BlueRose, Sorry I did not and I have no idea how to? Could you please provide me some links if you know any?

Answer (score 0):

1) While exporting the database form your server , use [WP Migrate Db Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)

Install the plugin on your main site and go to tools -> migrate Db, enter your localhost path as new path and click on export.
Now export this database to your localhost.

2) Make sure your .htaccess file has write permissions.
When you save your permalinks check if its showing any errors/suggestions below , if its .htacess issue than simply proved the write permission and re save the permalinks or manually copy the suggested code to .htaccess.